# SSH: Remote Host identification has changed

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a machine running ubuntu and another one that is a mac. They are connected to the same router.

In the past I could connect from my mac to the ubuntu one using ssh and the IP address and use of the ubuntu one.

On the side I am doing a lot of installing and upgrading in the ubuntu machine.

Then when I tried to access the ubuntu from the mac, I got the "Remote Host identification has change" error and I could not connect.

I searched the internet and I got resources like [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/warning-remote-host-identification-has-changed). Unfortunately my knowledge of SSH is low but I am willing to learn.

I got that for some reason I don't know, the SSH have changed. And that in line 2 of the file known as `known_hosts` there is the offending old key.

In the linked article it says that I should delete the offending line .

My question is: Is this referring to files in the mac machine right? (the client) 
And is this enough?

Another question is:

If I delete the line in `known_hosts` is this line going to be regenerated with the correct key when I connect again?

Can this be done using 
`ssh-keygen -R "you server hostname or ip"` ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Ubuntu machine's `sshd` host key probably changed because you didn't preserve it when doing an OS reinstall, so it had to generate a new one.

Yes, you can fix the error message on the client by deleting that line from your client's known_hosts file as you said.

Yes, `ssh-keygen -R hostname` does the same thing.

Yes, the when you connect the next time, it will ask you if you want to accept the (new) key, just like the first time.

Answer (score -2):

The fingerprint of the client has changed from the server view.
So you have to delete the line on the server under **known_hosts** containing your client ip, but it will be **regenerated** later when trying to **connect** to the client.

Also **"ssh-keygen -R ip_address"** will do the **same** thing : removing the line containing the fingerprint o the server side.

Comment: So I have to delete it on the SERVER??  I was going to do it on the client!!

Comment: This answers appear to swap server and client roles. Very confusing.

Comment: you have to do it on the client side, i have made mistake in the first paragraph but it's true on the second.